# Displaying radiobuttons not working properly in PHP/HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to do an insert statement for my survey but firstly the radiobuttons isn't displaying I think the script part isn't working properly. This is a survey form and my goal is to submit a survey.

EDITED (I think the script part isn't working)

```
     <div style="padding: 40px;">

       <iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>

      <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imetrics");

$id = $_REQUEST['survey_id'];
$count=1;
$answer=0;
    $query =  "SELECT SF.survey_id, SF.surveytitle, SF.surveycategory, C.categoryname, Q.Option_1, Q.Option_2, Q.Option_3, Q.Option_4, Q.Option_5, Q.Option_6, Q.Option_7, Q.Option_8, Q.Option_9, Q.Option_10 AS pcatname, SF.surveysubcategory, SC.categoryname AS scatname, SF.gender, SF.age, SF.occupation, O.name, SF.occupation_status, SF.status, SFQ.question_id, Q.questiontitle
     FROM surveyform AS SF 
    LEFT JOIN category AS C ON SF.surveycategory = C.category_id
    LEFT JOIN category AS SC ON SF.surveysubcategory = SC.category_id
    INNER JOIN occupation AS O ON SF.occupation = O.occupation_id
    INNER JOIN surveyform_questions AS SFQ ON SF.survey_id = SFQ.survey_id
    INNER JOIN question AS Q ON SFQ.question_id = Q.question_id
 WHERE SFQ.survey_id  = $id";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if($result) {
    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="insertsurvey.php" target="votar">
        <?php

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $questions = $row['questiontitle'];


            echo "<b>Question " . $count . ".)</b> " . $questions . "</br>";

            $option1 = $row['Option_1'];
            $option2 = $row['Option_2'];
            $option3 = $row['Option_3'];
            $option4 = $row['Option_4'];
            $option5 = $row['Option_5'];
            $option6 = $row['Option_6'];
            $option7 = $row['Option_7'];
            $option8 = $row['Option_8'];
            $option9 = $row['Option_9'];
            $option10 = $row['Option_10'];

            if (!is_null($option1)) {
                ?>
                <div id="question_<?php echo $count; ?>_option1" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]"  value="<?php echo $option1; ?>"> <?php echo $option1; ?>
                </div>
                <br>
                <?php

            }

            if (!is_null($option2)) {
                ?>

                <div id="question_<?php echo $count; ?>_option2" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]"
                           value="<?php echo $option2; ?>"> <?php echo $option2; ?>
                </div>
                <br>

                <?php

            }

            if (!is_null($option3)) {
                ?>


                <div id="question_<?php echo $count; ?>_option3" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]"
                           value="<?php echo $option3; ?>"> <?php echo $option3; ?>
                </div>
                <br>
            <?php }


            if (!is_null($option4)) {

                ?>


                <div id="question_<?php echo $count; ?>_option4" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]"
                           value="<?php echo $option4; ?>"> <?php echo $option4; ?>
                </div>
                <br>

            <?php }

            if (!is_null($option5)) {
                ?>


                <div id="question_<?php echo $count; ?>_option5" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]"
                           value="<?php echo $option5; ?>"> <?php echo $option5; ?>
                </div>
                <br>
            <?php }

            if (!is_null($option6)) {
                ?>


                <div id="question_<?php echo $count; ?>_option6" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]"
                           value="<?php echo $option6; ?>"> <?php echo $option6; ?>
                </div>
                <br>
            <?php }
            if (!is_null($option7)) {
                ?>


                <div id="question_<?php echo $count; ?>_option7" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]"
                           value="<?php echo $option7; ?>"> <?php echo $option7; ?>
                </div>
                <br>
            <?php }
            if (!is_null($option8)) {
                ?>


                <div id="question_<?php echo $count; ?>_option8" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]"
                           value="<?php echo $option8; ?>"> <?php echo $option8; ?>
                </div>
                <br>
            <?php }
            if (!is_null($option9)) {
                ?>


                <div id="question_<?php echo $count; ?>_option9" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]"
                           value="<?php echo $option9; ?>"> <?php echo $option9; ?>
                </div>
                <br>
            <?php }
            if (!is_null($option10)) {
                ?>
                <div id="question_<?php echo $count; ?>_option10" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]"
                           value="<?php echo $option10; ?>"> <?php echo $option10; ?>
                </div>
                <br>
            <?php }
            $count++;
        } ?>



    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>

            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                jQuery(function($) {

                    var id1 = <?php echo json_encode($option1); ?>;
                    var id2 = <?php echo json_encode($option2); ?>;
                    var id3 = <?php echo json_encode($option3); ?>;
                    var id4 = <?php echo json_encode($option4); ?>;
                    var id5 = <?php echo json_encode($option5); ?>;
                    var id6 = <?php echo json_encode($option6); ?>;
                    var id7 = <?php echo json_encode($option7); ?>;
                    var id8 = <?php echo json_encode($option8); ?>;
                    var id9 = <?php echo json_encode($option9); ?>;
                    var id10 = <?php echo json_encode($option10); ?>;


                    if (id1 != null) {
                        $("div#option1").show();
                    }

                    if (id2 != null) {
                        $("div#option2").show();
                    }

                    if (id3 != null) {
                        $("div#option3").show();
                    }

                    if (id4 != null) {
                        $("div#option4").show();
                    }

                    if (id5 != null) {
                        $("div#option5").show();
                    }

                    if (id6 != null) {
                        $("div#option6").show();
                    }

                    if (id7 != null) {
                        $("div#option7").show();
                    }

                    if (id8 != null) {
                        $("div#option8").show();
                    }

                    if (id9 != null) {
                        $("div#option9").show();
                    }

                    if (id10 != null) {
                        $("div#option10").show();
                    }

                })(jQuery);

            </script>



</div>
</div>
</body>
    </html>


            <?php

                    }

            ?>
```

[what my survey form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8v53.png)
[What the script part looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z75sf.png)

Comment: My retina literally burns each time I see people use code unaware of the vulnerability's to build into it. Yes, your code is liable to [sql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Please read the documentation on how to use prepared statements for [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). If you don't, be prepared that 1 day **your database is leaked to the web**.

Comment: learn tutorial or website that can help you first, I can't even understand your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem (aside from the SQL injection problem Xorifelse mentions) is with your HTML. The `name` attribute needs to be different for each question. Having it be the same is the reason your radio buttons are behaving the way they are.

You could do something like this (there are many ways to solve this problem):

`<input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"> <?php echo $value; ?>`

When you do this, PHP will (generally speaking... there are probably exceptions to this depending on server configuration) put this into an array, like:

`$_REQUEST['answer'] => array(
    1 => 'answer to question 1',
    2 => 'answer to question 2',
    etc
);`

You should note that incrementing your `$count` variable where you do will effectively "skip" question one, so you should move that to the end of your `while () { }` block:

`while (condition) {
    ...
    $count++;
}`

Oh, and about your submit button problem, just put it outside of the `while` loop and you'll be fine:

```
<?php
    while (condition) {
        // do all your stuff

        $count++;
    }
?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Edit below for a more complete example.

**Please note:** What you're doing explicitly referencing $option1 through $option10 is just *begging* for a loop, but I've left it as you had it for clarity and so it's easier to follow along. This isn't really how I'd do it, but it is closest to your original code for easy of understanding.

```
<?php

    // all your same stuff before this mysqli_query call...

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    if ($result) {
?>
        <form action="php-file.php" method="post">
<?php

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $questions = $row['questiontitle'];

            echo "<b>Question " . $count . "</b> " . $questions . "<br>";

            $option1 = $row['Option_1'];
            $option2 = $row['Option_2'];
            $option3 = $row['Option_3'];
            $option4 = $row['Option_4'];
            $option5 = $row['Option_5'];
            $option6 = $row['Option_6'];
            $option7 = $row['Option_7'];
            $option8 = $row['Option_8'];
            $option9 = $row['Option_9'];
            $option10 = $row['Option_10'];

            if (!is_null($option1)) {
        ?>
                <div id="question_<?php echo $count; ?>_option1" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option1; ?>"> <?php echo $option1; ?>
                </div>
                <br>
        <?php
            } // if

            if (!is_null($option2)) {
        ?>
                <div id="question_<?php echo $count; ?>_option2" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option2; ?>"> <?php echo $option2; ?>
                </div>
                <br>
        <?php
            } // if

            if (!is_null($option3)) {
        ?>
                <div id="question_<?php echo $count; ?>_option3" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option3; ?>"> <?php echo $option3; ?>
                </div>
                <br>
        <?php
            } // if

            // options 4-9 here, the exact same way as option 1-3 above

            if (!is_null($option10)) {
        ?>
                <div id="question_<?php echo $count; ?>_option10" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option10; ?>"> <?php echo $option10; ?>
                </div>
                <br>
        <?php
            } // if

            $count++;

        } // end while
?>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>

<?php

    } // end if (result)
```

---

Here's what your solution *could* be (I think). Note that I've replaced your explicit `$optionX` definitions with a loop. The reason you don't need the javascript is because you're already checking with the PHP whether the option exists, so you should be able to safely display it--without the `display: hidden;` style.

```
<?php

    # this stuff removed for brevity, but you'd just put the same stuff you had originally

    if ($result) {
?>
    <form method="POST" action="insertsurvey.php" target="votar">
<?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $questions = $row['questiontitle'];

            echo "<b>Question " . $count . ".)</b> " . $questions . "<br>";

            for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
                if (!empty($row['Option_' . $i])) {
        ?>
                <div id="question_<?php echo $count; ?>_option<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $count; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['Option_' . $i]; ?>"> <?php echo $row['Option_' . $i]; ?>
                </div>
        <?php
                }
            }

            $count++;
        }

        ?>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>

    <!-- no javascript/jquery script needed anymore; though obviously you'd want to restore it if you have javascript doing something else -->

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where do I put the opening <form> tag in that case? @Davis

Comment: @Jola, anywhere above your `where` loop should be fine.  After your `if ($result)` would be fine.  It will be clearer in the future if you open and close within that `if` or outside of it, but either will work.

Comment: Thanks. I just realized I have bigger problems though :( I right clicked inspect element on each radio button on question number one and the value of  the three radio buttons in question number one is answerone,answertwo,answerthree(edited the names in the input already) that's a big problem since i only want those three to have one value/name. @davis

Comment: Hm... I'm not sure I understand what's happening. Can you update your question with the additional details?

Comment: Updated sir @davis

Comment: @Jola, okay, I see now. I suggest using the form I gave in my answer, where you would use your `$count` variable to create a unique name for all the answers to a given question. That will make your radio buttons work correctly, and will only give you one answer per question when you process the form on the receiving end. Does that make sense?

Comment: A little bit can you please answer in code format I'm really bad in understanding things :( @Davis

Comment: @Jola, please see my edits for a more complete example of what I mean.

Comment: Do I put the rest of the answers in the middle php tags where you put the count? @Davis What's the format? Do I still put the if(!is_null) for each answer?

Comment: Yes, you put all the other options just as you had them, patterned after the example I gave for "option1."

Comment: So I'll make 9 more php tags and and $count++ on each one of them? @davis

Comment: No, only one $count++; One for the loop, right before it loops. Your option sections are the same, with the exception of the change I made to the "name" attribute. Note how I added `[<?php echo $count; ?>]` to it. That's what you need to change.

Comment: How would I include the       <div id="option2" style="display:none;">
                        <input type="radio" name="answer_<?php echo $answer ?>" value="<?php echo $option2;?>" id="<?php echo $option2 ?>"><?php echo $option2 ?>
                    </div>
                    <br /> inside the php tags though? @Davis

Comment: @Jola, I've updated my answer to make it more clear how you would add the additional options. Please note I also made the `id` of the containing `<div>` such that it would be unique on the page. I must say I don't understand why you have those divs hidden, but there you have it.

Comment: @Jola, have you had a chance to implement the changes detailed in my answer above?

Comment: Sorry for very late reply we lost electricity in my 3rd world country anyways I edited my question with your code but it seems that the radio buttons isn't displaying. I've put a picture so you can see what it looks like. @Davis

Comment: Once, SO prompted me to take my conversation into a private one. It's not doing it here for some reason, and I'm not sure how to do it myself.  So, @Jola, I don't think you need the script part at all. Your PHP is checking that an option exists before displaying the button; your JS seems to be trying to do the same thing. But, we changed the div names. ...  See my edit for what I think you could do here instead.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to do this code very soon but at the moment my creating question with answer type has option1-10 column in its database table and I think it's a really bad idea since a question can have more than 10 radio buttons as an option. I will need to learn how to create a question with radiobuttons in a way that I can insert as many radio buttons as I can in 1 question? Can you help me sir @davis?

Comment: Sure, I can help. It's getting messy here though... if SO will let me put this here, go ahead and email me at davis-so@mail.com and we can figure this out.